# Cors блокирует совпадающий origin

Tags: cors

По какой-то причине браузер блокирует редирект с сервера из-зы CORS политики, хотя origin правильный

[image: ошибка CORS]
[image: запрос на сервер]
[image: сервер редиректит]

Comment: схема в origin не входит, только хост и порт

Comment: @PavelMayorov, действительно, посмотрел Origin у редиректа, Origin: null, буду думать почему fetch его не ставит...